# jstree, json, ajax: Recursive Search and Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

I have jstree setup to load all content via ajax and json. Is it possible for the script to execute my ajax/json url and keep sub-searching when possible, if it finds it open all sub nodes until its visible and select it (.jstree-clicked). And is such a feature built in, if not know any where I could start with this? I am not the most fluent at javascript.
Here is my setup:

```
$("#jstFormMirror").jstree({
    "types" : { 
        "types" : { 
            "default" : { 
                "select_node" : function(e) {
                    this.toggle_node(e);
                    return true;
                } 
            }
        } 
    },
    "ui" : {
        "select_limit" : 1,
        "selected_parent_close" : "select_parent"
    },      
    "json_data" : {
        "progressive_unload" : true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "/back-end/json/categories.json",
            "data" : function (n) {
                return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 }; 
            }
        }
    },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "types", "ui" ],
    "core": {
        "animation": 100
    }
}).bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) { 
    $("#category").val($(".jstree-clicked").parent().attr("rel"));
})
```

And he is a typical json response when the script loads a node:

```
[
    {
        "attr": {
            "id": "87"
        },
        "data": {
            "title": "Bevel Clusters-Over 350 Designs",
            "attr": {
                "href": "#",
                "rel": "658"
            }
        },
        "state": "closed"
    },
    {
        "attr": {
            "id": "394"
        },
        "data": {
            "title": "Bevels, Straight Lines-Over 210 Shapes & Sizes",
            "attr": {
                "href": "#",
                "rel": "321"
            }
        },
        "state": "closed"
    }
]
```

I want to execute:

```
$("#jstFormCategories").jstree("search", ID_HERE);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, DefiantJS is excellent (http://defiantjs.com).
This lib extends the global object JSON with the method "search" and enables you to search a JSON structure with XPath expressions.

To understand how easy XPath (which is a standardised query language) is, check out this tool;
http://www.defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator

Here is a working fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/vV43F/

```
var data = [
     {
        "attr": {
           "id": "87"
        },
        "data": {
           "title": "Bevel Clusters-Over 350 Designs",
           "attr": {
              "href": "#",
              "rel": "658"
           }
        },
        "state": "closed"
     },
     {
        "attr": {
           "id": "394"
        },
        "data": {
           "title": "Bevels, Straight Lines-Over 210 Shapes & Sizes",
           "attr": {
              "href": "#",
              "rel": "321"
           }
        },
        "state": "closed"
     }
  ],
  res = JSON.search( data, '//*[id=394]/../data' );

console.log( res[0].title );
```